# Check if layer is a QGSVectorLayer from Python Plugin within QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I am trying to extend some concepts in the [QGIS Workshop tutorial](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html).  Basically, I would like to check if the layer is of type "QGSVectorLayer".  In the QGIS Python console, I am able to type

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
cLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
type(cLayer).__name__
```

with no problem.  However, when attempting the same from the plugin, I get the following error message:

> if type(self.cLayer).**name** == "QgsVectorLayer": NameError: global
>   name 'cLayer' is not defined

The code is as follows:

```
def handleLayerChange(self, layer):
        self.cLayer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
        if self.cLayer:
            if type(self.cLayer).__name__ == "QgsVectorLayer":
                self.provider = self.cLayer.dataProvider()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to compare it using strings or the name of the type.  You should just do:

```
 layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much better.  I did end up getting the other method to work by converting it to a string; if str(type(self.cLayer).__name__) == "QgsVectorLayer"

Comment: The pythonic, recommended way is using `isinstance` as suggested in @KitKat's answer!

Answer (score 10):

Another way is testing against the desired class type, like this:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

# ...
if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
    # ...
```