# Getting all shapefile layers in project using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, vector-layer, extensions, qgs

I'm writing a plugin that needs to check a few things for every shapefile layer in the current project. I am iterating over the layers as shown below, but cant figure out how to check if it is a shapefile. I don't consider using the URI to be a reliable method.

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    dp = layer.dataProvider()
    uri = dp.dataSourceUri()
    if dp.storageFormat() == 'shapefile': # not valid code
        print(dp) 
        #verify stuff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shapefile format is a geospatial ***Vector*** data format, therefore on **a first stage** I suggest to catch all of vector layers with the [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) class.

There are several approaches to achieve it with:

- the [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function:

```py
   isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer)
```

- the [`.type()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Map/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.type) method from the [`QgsMapLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Map/QgsMapLayer.html#module-QgsMapLayer) class:

  ```py
  layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer
  ```
- the [`.name()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Data/QgsDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsDataProvider.name) method from the [`QgsDataProvider`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Data/QgsDataProvider.html) class:

  ```py
  layer.dataProvider().name() == 'ogr'
  ```

  Here is a list of all [ogr drivers](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html):

  > ['ARCGEN', 'AVCBin', 'AVCE00', 'AmigoCloud', 'BAG', 'CAD', 'CSV',
  > 'CSW', 'Carto', 'Cloudant', 'CouchDB', 'DB2ODBC', 'DGN', 'DXF',
  > 'EDIGEO', 'EEDA', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'ESRIC', 'ESRIJSON',
  > 'Elasticsearch', 'FlatGeobuf', 'GML', 'GMLAS', 'GPKG', 'GPSBabel',
  > 'GPSTrackMaker', 'GPX', 'GeoJSON', 'GeoJSONSeq', 'GeoRSS',
  > 'Geoconcept', 'Geomedia', 'HTTP', 'Idrisi', 'Interlis 1', 'Interlis
  > 2', 'JML', 'JP2ECW', 'JP2OpenJPEG', 'KML', 'LIBKML', 'LVBAG',
  > 'MBTiles', 'MSSQLSpatial', 'MVT', 'MapInfo File', 'MapML', 'Memory',
  > 'MySQL', 'NAS', 'NGW', 'OAPIF', 'OCI', 'ODBC', 'ODS', 'OGCAPI',
  > 'OGR_GMT', 'OGR_OGDI', 'OGR_PDS', 'OGR_SDTS', 'OGR_VRT', 'OSM',
  > 'OpenFileGDB', 'PCIDSK', 'PDF', 'PDS4', 'PGDUMP', 'PGeo', 'PLSCENES',
  > 'PostgreSQL', 'REC', 'S57', 'SOSI', 'SQLite', 'SVG', 'SXF', 'Selafin',
  > 'TIGER', 'TopoJSON', 'UK .NTF', 'VDV', 'VFK', 'VICAR', 'WAsP', 'WFS',
  > 'Walk', 'XLS', 'XLSX', 'netCDF']

  More information can be found under [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook 1.0 documentation | Vector Layers](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#vector-layers).

After that all the vector layers will be available:

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
        print(layer)
```

However, at this point there should be considered **a second stage** to distinct between types of the vector layer: shapefile, GeoPackage, GeoJSON etc. There are several ideas, that use:

- the [`.storageType()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.storageType) function:

  ```py
   for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
       if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
           if layer.storageType() == 'ESRI Shapefile':
               print(layer)
  ```
- the [`.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Data/QgsDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsDataProvider.dataSourceUri) methods combination:

  ```py
   for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
       if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
           if '.shp' in layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri():
               print(layer)
  ```
- the [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) function from the `os.path` module:

  ```py
   from os.path import split

   for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
       if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
           dir_name, file_name = os.path.split(layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
           if '.shp' in file_name:
               print(layer)
  ```
- the [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function from the `os.path` module:

  ```py
   from os.path import splitext

   for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
       if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
           file_name, file_extension = splitext(layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
           if '.shp' in file_extension:
               print(layer)
  ```

As an alternative one can use:

- the [`.source()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Map/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.source)  method from the [`QgsMapLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Map/QgsMapLayer.html#module-QgsMapLayer) class

  ```py
   for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
       if '.shp' in layer.source():
           print(layer)
  ```

---

**References:**

- [Check if layer is a QGSVectorLayer from Python Plugin within QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60269/check-if-layer-is-a-qgsvectorlayer-from-python-plugin-within-qgis)
- [Getting path of project, or layer file in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34560/getting-path-of-project-or-layer-file-in-pyqgis)
- [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)
- [Check if a word is in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/check-if-a-word-is-in-a-string-in-python)